# Function composition with just lambdas in python

Tags: python, lambda, function-composition

Is there a way to do the following in just one line with lambdas in python?

```py
squared = lambda x : x**2
cubed = lambda x : x**3
squareCubed = lambda x : squared(cubed(x))
```

without using any helper functions or reduce.

```py
print(squareCubed(2)) # > 64
```

Comment: Yes... replace `cubed` with `lambda x: x**3` and `squared` with `lambda x: x**2`??

Comment: It certainly can be done. As prev. comment shown.  But ... why?

Comment: It was an interview question.

Comment: @cvb0rg that's a pretty terrible interview question

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do something like:

```
squareCube = (lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)))(lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**3)
```

But why do this?

In any case, you shouldn't be assigning the result of `lambda` to a variable if you are following the official PEP8 style guide. What is wrong with:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2

def cube(x):
    return x**3

def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

square_cube = compose(square, cube)
```

Is much more readable.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. I'm a bit confused as to how in ```var = () ()``` the first parentheses know to look in the 2nd () for the definitions of f and g?

Comment: The first parentheses just groups `(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)))(lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**3)`, this results in a function (of course - it is a lambda expression), you then **call** that function, passing it the corresponding arguments. It's exactly like the more readable version I showed below it

Answer (score 0):

```
squareCubed = lambda x : (x**3)**2

print(squareCubed(2)) # gives 64
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32465195)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hard code it:

```py
squareCube = lambda x: (x**3)**2
```

But generically:

```py
compose = lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x))
squareCube = compose(lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**3)
```

Or, in one line:

```py
squareCube = (lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)))(lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**3)
```